# Add member to Group in XMPP

Tags: android, xmpp, openfire, smack, asmack

I managed to create a user in my xmpp server successfully(asmack).

```
AccountManager am = m_connection.getAccountManager();
am.createAccount(mUserName, "1234");
```

However, now I want to add this newley created user to a group programmatically.
I cant find any examples or documentation on this I can do this very easily on th server itself but I need to do this programmatically...Thanks for your help!

EDIT:

I installed a plug in subscribe that autammtically accepts subscription reqests see below image. And now I am calling roster.createEntry but still doesnt work any Idea?

```
AccountManager am = new AccountManager(m_connection);
        am.createAccount(mUserName, "1234");

        m_connection.login(mUserName, "1234");
        Roster roster = m_connection.getRoster();
        String[] urlArray = new String[] { "DOLPHIN" };


        roster.createEntry(mUserName, mUserName, urlArray);
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why don't use `MultiUserChat`(muc) to create groups? Note: I am newbie in xmpp.

Comment: @AwadKab because MUC has nothing to do with user groups.

Comment: You mean your server is Openfire, right? By "adding to groups", do you mean Openfire groups, or roster groups? Does the "Registration" plugin work for you?

Comment: How is this question different from your other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15821812/add-user-to-rostergroup-in-smack, by the way?

Comment: @BenCompanjen As per mu understanding there is no difference between a RosterGroup and a Group. No? There is no difference between the other question  I plan to close it...sorry

Comment: An Openfire group can be used as an easy way to group users and optionally show them as roster groups, but the other way around does not work. Each user is free to create any number of groups in his/her own roster. The *Registration* plugin automatically assigns new users to a group. More advanced group assignment can be performed by users with admin rights from clients, but I don't know what messages are used to perform user management actions.

Comment: Thanks Ben! I know about the Registration plug in but I need to attach a different user to a different Group/RosterGroup. So that plug in doesnt help me . Any other idea?